# Delete a range from start to finish with SED

Tags: regex, sed

I need to remove and delete header from html files. `//I want to identify <head> and delete all content until </head>.`

`sed '/^<head>$/,/^<\/head>$/d' 6.php`

I am using a terminal connection for server access from a Mac. Ive used many combinations and the one above worked (once) but can not get it to work again.

Where I am messing it up? Do I need to add a library to get this to work

Comment: *to work again* - for multiple files? loop through the files

Comment: This works for me
Single file: `sed '/<head>/,/<\/head>/d' hello.php`
Multiple files: `ls *.php | xargs sed '/<head>/,/<\/head>/d' `

Comment: Note that `<head>` can be on the same line as something else.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I tested on hello.php test file that had the string in it that was successfully removed. I tried it on a different file  hello1.php and it did not work.

Comment: Your sed line `sed '/^<head>$/...` only triggers if "<head>" is alone on a line, not even whitespace. @Vivek proposed a line `sed '/<head>/...` which matches more generously. Is that relevant? I could imagine a slightly to "simple" test file. Be careful, the generous match might delete more than you want.

Comment: @Vivek that worked like a champ. I also used the Multiple files and it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

This works for me Single file:

```
sed '/<head>/,/<\/head>/d' hello.php
```

Multiple files:

```
ls *.php | xargs sed '/<head>/,/<\/head>/d'
```

(Quoting @Vivek, just to make a Q/A pair.)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
# case of both on same line
   \!<head>.*</head>! s////
# if occur, continue to next line
   t
# other case, delete line, after <head>, before </head> (including)
   /<head>/,\!</head>! {
      s/<head>.*//;t
      s!.*</head>//;t
      d
      }
  ' YourFile
```

assume there is no funny `<head>` inside *head* section